# Regex not Triggering VBA

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, regexbuddy

This is my regex:

```
    Dim vbRegX As Object, vbRegXMatch As Object
    Set vbRegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With vbRegX
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}$"
    End With
```

code that uses it:

```
    Set vbRegXMatch = vbRegX.Execute(Me.txtProduct.Text)
    If vbRegXMatch.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "This string has invalid characters in it. Illegal characters are out side of the following ranges:" & vbNewLine & vbNewling & "a-z or A-Z" & vbNewLine & vbNewling & "0-9, - or _. Please try again."
        Cancel = True
        Me.txtProduct.SetFocus
        Set vbRegXMatch = Nothing
        Set vbRegX = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This code fires with invalid characters but not when length is > 20. This is the output given to me by Regex Buddy:

```
Dim FoundMatch As Boolean
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}$"
FoundMatch = myRegExp.Test(SubjectString)
```

Can anyone so kindly point out what Im missing?

visual of the control:

[image]

Comment: Isn't `^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}$` validating the *good* input? Use it like `If myRegExp.Test(Me.txtProduct.Text) = False Then`

Comment: Not when length is > 20. It does fire with invalid characters though.

Comment: It works fine - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VqO4LM/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Thanks but its isnt firing when this occurs - see edited post.

Comment: `If vbRegX.Test("1234555") = False Then` works, it does not fire any error. `If vbRegX.Test("123455=5") = False Then` works, too, it fires the error.

Comment: Ok I was testing the regex incorrectly. Post as answer if you want the creds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches *valid* input. Thus, you need to `.Test(your_string)` and if the result is `False`, you need to fire an error.

Replace

```
Set vbRegXMatch = vbRegX.Execute(Me.txtProduct.Text)
If vbRegXMatch.Count = 1 Then
```

with

```
If vbRegX.Test("1234555") = False Then
```

Also, since you expect a single match, use

```
.Global = False
```